# A fun and simple Nonogram... ...with a cipher

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, cipher, grid-deduction, nonogram

Goal of this puzzle: Find the hidden message in this Nonogram that I created.

The puzzle:

[image]

[play online](http://www.landofcrispy.com/nonogrammer/nonogram.html?mode=play&puzzle=12%7C13%7C1x1.1x2.1x3.1x1,1x1.1x2,1x3.1x1,1x3.1x1.1x2,1x1.1x1,1x3.1x1.1x2.1x2,1x1.1x2.1x3.1x3,1x1,1x1.1x4.1x2,1x2.1x1,1x1.1x2,1x3%7C1x1.1x1.1x2.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x2.1x2,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x2.1x1,1x2.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x2.1x1,1x2%7Cx,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,0,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,0,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,0,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x&palette=white.grey.X,black..)

Hint:

> You should get Morse code if it is solved correctly.

Comment: Is the nonogram solution definitely unique here?

Comment: @hexomino Yes it is most definitely unique (the website would tell you if it's correct if you chose to use the online link)

Comment: Used the information in the above comment to solve the nonogram, site said "solved" so it should be correct, can't see anything that would look like the thing mentioned in the spoiler block though.

Comment: @Bass Take the top 2 rows and split them from the rest, do the same thing until they are all separated, you should have what the spoiler block mentions.

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting way to encode it. Answer coming up.

Comment: @Bass Yeah, I probably should have mentioned my method of encoding that data in the spoiler block lol, although good job on solving it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it wasn't part of the original question, in the comments OP gave out this invaluable nugget of information:

> [image]

Since the nonogram was definitely difficult enough to warrant such trickery, that information enables a [Forbidden Technique™](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJliK881Leo) to get through a particularly difficult bit near the middle of the solve:

> [image]

The green squares form a ["deadly pattern"](https://sudoku.ironmonger.com/howto/deadlyPattern/docs.tpl): they contain one coloured block each, one on each row, and the pattern is such that the row and column clues cannot possibly disambiguate between the two options. Since we have as a given the information that there is a unique solution, that pattern must somehow be resolved, and the only way that can happen is if there is a coloured block at the red circle.

After that, the solution was again more or less straightforward, and here's the finished grid:

> [image]

The encoded message was a lot harder to find, but with OP's help, I finally figured out the encoding:

> consider the lines as pairs; bottom row is "dit", top row is "dah"

This gives the message

> ```
>  you
>  sol
>  vedi
>  tgoo
>  d1m
>  t7
> ```

the end of which suggests that maybe I have forgotten how to read morse code :-)

<sub><sup>(EDIT: turns out my morse is fine, OP's puzzle creation tools had suffered a stronk.)</sup></sub>

Comment: the "1mt7" should be "job" but I think that's just an encoding mistake (i can check), but yeah you basically solved it correctly. edit: yeah it's an encoding mistake lol but you can still have the green checkmark (edited 21:06 UTC)